# SSIS: using parameters from configuration file

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an SSIS package that contains one data flow task that has several data sources as well as several destinations. The package takes data fro one table and inserts it into another. 
I want to transfer from Source table to destination table only records that belong to a particular CollectionID. I added a parameter "CollectionID" of type string to the project and added the parameter to the configuration file.

I select data from the source table via SQL command. How can I get the sql command to use the parameter I added to the configuration file? I understand I need to add a WHERE clause, but how do I point the where clause to a parameter in the config file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a variable and map it to the configuration value.

Assuming you are using the OLE connection type, you then map the variable value to the SQL statement with the ? placeholder.

```
SELECT * from Table where columnvalue = ?
```

Finally, map the variable in the ExecuteSQL task:
[image: VariableMapping]

If the parameter doesn't have a name you can just use 0, but make sure the data type is correct.  If it is a text data type, you will need to give it the proper length, not -1.

Comment: Thank you! I actually do not use Execute SQL task, I have my sql statement in the OLE DB Source as a way to pull data. Would that make a difference?

Comment: That should work and is actually how I usually do it.  I grabbed the execute SQL task instead for the example, but the principle is the same.